# How do I get the width of a row (multiple cells)?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to get the width of a row (made out of several cells)

I've tried this:

```
$this->objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$this->objDrawing->setCoordinates('A12:I12');
$this->objDrawing->getWidth();
```

..and getWidth() returns 0, even though on A12:I12 I have content in each cell.

Why is that getWidth(); returning 0, when I'm expecting it to return total width of the row? So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width is set when you add a file to the drawing object, and is based on the width of the image file (with any proportional adjustments), not of the columns that it occupies.

**EDIT**

For calculating the width of a range of columns in a worksheet:

```
$defaultColumnWidth = $pSheet->getDefaultColumnDimension()->getWidth();
```

will give you the default width for each column unless it is explicitly overridden; though you'd normally use 9.10 for this.

Then for each individual columnDimension, check the defined width and whether autosize is enabled:

If autosize is enabled, then you need to calculate the width that will be used based on the content of all values in that column

Use the worksheets calculateColumnWidths() method.

This will set columnDimension widths to the calculated value, which you can then use.

Watch out for hidden or collapsed columns.

Comment: I need to center the image within the row, so I need the width of the row, I already have the width of the image. Do you know how I can center an image within a row, other than what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: It's not easy to do: You'd need to work out the dimensions for each column and do some math from that

Comment: Ok, then it all comes down to: how do I get the width of a column? Like I said, getWidth(); returns 0. If I do $this->objDrawing->setCoordinates('A'); or A1 it returns 640, which is odd, and obviously false. Btw, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: If they are manually set column widths (e.g. you've set them yourself, or from a loaded file), then these can be retrieved from the columnDimension object; otherwise they need to be calculated as though they were autosize columns

Comment: All of my columns are autosize, I have no idea how to do that. I suppose this I found is for the columns with set dimensions as you said $calculatedWidth = $sheet->getColumnDimension($i)->getWidth(); So how do I 'calculate' the width of an autosize column?